# Jquery datatables first result always stays in table

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, knockout.js, datatables

I created an ASP.NET page that sends some request and gets results.

After I get the results I format it into the HTML table. The results can be different by number of columns and rows.

After that I am trying to use datatables to get it formated and easy to view and search, and it works fine, but only the first time it is called. (I get results on button click.)

For example, let's say I only get 1 parameter and value (`name-status`, `value-ok`), and it will be shown like this under, and that is ok

```
status
ok
```

but after i call it again, let's say I will get the same respond results, the results are shown like this

```
status   status
ok
ok
```

for every next call the output table will stay the same, it will show the first result I get, and the last one

how can I get rid of the first one?

I tried destroying datatable, tblResults, old values in results- pretty much everything that came to my mind

HTML table:

```
<table id="tblResults">
    <thead id="tblHead">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: reportHeaders">
            <th data-bind="text: $data"></th>
        </tr>  
    </thead>

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: reportResults">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: rowArray">
          <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


self.reportResults.removeAll();
self.reportHeaders.removeAll();
ko.mapping.fromJS(results.d.results, mappingReportResults, self.reportResults);
ko.mapping.fromJS(results.d.header, self.reportHeaders);
oTable = $('#tblResults').dataTable();
```

Comment: I wonder if the `knockout.js` binding is conflicting with the default datatables binding - I'm not familiar with knockout at all, so it's only a guess.

Comment: it shouldn't be the problem as far as I know, it is weird to me that if I will get 5 different results to show(even columns), it will always show the first one and the last one